# Two answers for one question

Tags: discussion, answers

In reviewing the answers to [How can I show the value of best practices?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/400/104) I developed, and wrote up, an answer that I think is good. Which isn't saying that the other answers are not. Then, when I went to post it (draft written locally), I realized one of the other answers was mine. (Oops.) The new answer is not an expansion of the first. It is a different view, and different solution. Both are not "short" answers, though they aren't *big* posts either.

Is it better to post the new idea as an update to the first answer, which isn't related in concept, or should I post a second answer to the question and allow the votes to decide which is better?

Comment: If they're different, then post different answers. If one is an expansion on the other, then you should edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by [thesecretmaster](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/two-answers-for-one-question#comment288_160) is spot on. If your answers cannot stand separately, they should be edits. Otherwise, it's fine to post two answers, to allow the community to vote separately and the best answer to rise to the top. Ultimately, your decision; as long as the two answers are valid solutions to the problem asked, I can't see any real problems with answering multiple times with distinct solutions.

See also: [**What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) on Meta Stack Exchange, for further context.